# PHP session var both is and is not set?

Tags: php, session, isset

Here's a little piece of code, copied and pasted verbatim from the top of a single .php file:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

require_once('rb.php');
require_once('Util.php');

echo("Here is the session: ");
echo(print_r($_SESSION, true));
$isDevel = $_SESSION['isDevel'];
print_r("isDevel is: $isDevel\n");

if (! isset($_SESSION['isDevel'])) {
    die("connections.php: isDevel needs to be set by now!  SESSION: " . 
      print_r($_SESSION, true));
}
```

Here's the output, in the course of execution:

```
Here is the session: Array
(
    [isDevel] => This is a string.
    [configObj] => 
)
isDevel is: This is a string.
connections.php: isDevel needs to be set by now! SESSION: Array ( [isDevel] => This is a string. [configObj] => )
```

Clearly $_SESSION['isDevel'] is set, otherwise I wouldn't be able to print it out.  But the `isset` test fails, claiming that `$_SESSION['isDevel']` isn't defined, and yet in the same breath, printing it out nonetheless!

I've checked the docs but I can't see how I'm screwing this up.

**EDIT:**

J A asked for the code where something gets assigned to the session.  It's this (from another file):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
$isDevel = 'This is a string.';
$_SESSION['isDevel'] = $isDevel;
```

Chris comments that he doesn't think I ran the same code I posted.  Not true.  Although perhaps you mean that there's more going on than just the code posted here?  If so, then yes, but since the code is spread over several files, I cannot condense it better than I already have.

Regardless, let me be explicit: the code I posted above is getting executed, exactly as you see it, in the order that you see it.  [Although I see that I've left out an echo() so that the first print_r isn't visible -- I'll fix that in the pre-edit problem description, to avoid too much confusion; and I'll add the two require_once targets that I omitted for clarity, so that the code is a verbatim copy and paste.]  So somehow, even though we can *see* the damn isDevel in the $_SESSION array, it's failing the isset test.

I'm at least gratified that people suspect me of foul play, since it proves the issue is subtle enough to bely an obvious explanation :)

**EDIT 2:**

It is embarrassing to report this, but I feel I owe it to folks who took the time to try to help me out.  The issue was a copy and paste error -- the code I reported did, in fact get executed.  But the code I quoted was not the code responsible for the output "isDevel needs to be set by now!"  Rather, I had erroneously cut and pasted that msg, and then forgot to edit the text to reflect the semantics of where I pasted it to.  So the code was getting executed, but it was not exhibiting the weird behavior I attributed to it.

Sorry for wasting your collective time.  I should have been smarter about this bug search.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you assigned the value of $_SESSION['isDevel']?

Comment: I don't think you actually ran the same code you posted here for us. I think you summarized it, and left out an important detail.

Comment: Try removing the space between `!` and `isset`.

Comment: Removing the space does nothing.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Did you build it yourself? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Start the session before you check session variables.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['isDevel'])) {
//code here
}
```

Comment: The first line of the code I quoted starts a session.  But just in case, I did it your way (which will result in warning messages in the event the session is already started.)  No luck.